# Taking a variable value at runtime in Grunt-Concat task

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-concat

I have implemented below Grunt configuration for concating two css files into a single css file(common_tfn_bsa.min.css ) in my jsp file.

```
<!-- build:css ./assets/css/common_tfn_bsa.min.css -->
  <link href="./${theme}/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="./${theme}/css/component.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- endbuild -->
```

But while running Grunt task above code is generated as :

```
    concat:
   { generated: 
   { files: 
       [ { dest: '.tmp\\concat\\assets\\css\\common_bom.min.css',
           src: 
           [ '.\\app\\${theme}\\css\\style.css',
              '.\\app\\${theme}\\css\\component.css' ] }
        ]
    }
    }
```

What I need is ,the value of **${theme}** in generated file so that it can pick the css files from correct location for concat.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<!-- build:css(./<%= theme %>) ./assets/css/common_tfn_bsa.min.css -->
  <link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="/css/component.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- endbuild -->
```